# Shortcut to unminimize window

Tags: shortcut-keys

I find myself accidentally hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> which minimizes the current window. How do I quickly unminimize it? I would prefer to leave the minimize shortcut enabled since I do use it intentionally on occasion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will bring the first window back.